# Retrieving a specific value from a column and store it in a new column depending on the conditions that has been set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas and I need help. I have a set of data as given:

| Index | sensor | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | temperature | 10/09/2019 10:49:00 |
| 1 | humidity | 10/09/2019 10:50:00 |
| 2 | light | 10/09/2019 10:50:00 |
| 3 | motion | 10/09/2019 10:50:00 |
| 4 | temperature | 10/09/2019 11:19:00 |
| 5 | humidity | 10/09/2019 11:20:00 |
| 6 | light | 10/09/2019 11:20:00 |
| 7 | motion | 10/09/2019 11:20:00 |
| 8 | temperature | 10/09/2019 11:34:00 |

Given data is not quite systematic for me, thus I want to add a new column named `temperature` and store its corresponding `timestamp` values.

I want to make a new column named `Temperature` and store it's corresponding timestamp value. The expected dataframe would be like the figure:

| index | sensor | timestamp | temperature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | temperature | 10/09/2019 10:49:00 | 10/09/2019 10:49:00 |
| 1 | humidity | 10/09/2019 10:50:00 | not related |
| 2 | light | 10/09/2019 10:50:00 | not related |
| 3 | motion | 10/09/2019 10:50:00 | not related |
| 4 | temperature | 10/09/2019 11:19:00 | 10/09/2019 11:19:00 |
| 5 | humidity | 10/09/2019 11:20:00 | not related |
| 6 | light | 10/09/2019 11:20:00 | not related |
| 7 | motion | 10/09/2019 11:20:00 | not related |
| 8 | temperature | 10/09/2019 11:34:00 | 10/09/2019 11:34:00 |

The idea that I've come out with is that I inspect each row in the `sensor` column to either contain `temperature` or not. I've created an empty list so that I could append the value and add it to the original dataframe later on.

```
List = []
```

If `sensor = 'temperature'` then the timestamp value will be stored in the new column and 'not_related' is given when `sensor != 'temperature'`. I tried to convert the idea into codes and this is where I am stuck.

```
for row in df['sensor']:
    if row == 'temperature' : List.append(df.loc[df[df['sensor']=='temperature'].index.values , 'timestamp'])
    else : List.append('Not related')
```

The problem with the code is that it stored **all** of the timestamp value that is equal to `temperature` and not its corresponding single value.

Example of what I get when I run these codes:

```
List[4]
```

```
0       2019-10-09 10:49:00
4       2019-10-09 11:19:00
8       2019-10-09 11:34:00
12      2019-10-09 11:49:00
16      2019-10-09 12:04:00
                ...        
86703   2021-03-22 13:29:00
86898   2021-03-25 14:36:00
86903   2021-03-25 14:51:00
86944   2021-03-28 16:52:00
87325   2021-07-19 10:03:00
Name: timestamp, Length: 8236, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

```
List[1]
```

`'Not related'`

```
List[0:5]
```

```
[0       2019-10-09 10:49:00
 4       2019-10-09 11:19:00
 8       2019-10-09 11:34:00
 12      2019-10-09 11:49:00
 16      2019-10-09 12:04:00
                 ...        
 86703   2021-03-22 13:29:00
 86898   2021-03-25 14:36:00
 86903   2021-03-25 14:51:00
 86944   2021-03-28 16:52:00
 87325   2021-07-19 10:03:00
 Name: timestamp, Length: 8236, dtype: datetime64[ns],
 'Not related',
 'Not related',
 'Not related',
 0       2019-10-09 10:49:00
 4       2019-10-09 11:19:00
 8       2019-10-09 11:34:00
 12      2019-10-09 11:49:00
 16      2019-10-09 12:04:00
                 ...        
 86703   2021-03-22 13:29:00
 86898   2021-03-25 14:36:00
 86903   2021-03-25 14:51:00
 86944   2021-03-28 16:52:00
 87325   2021-07-19 10:03:00
 Name: timestamp, Length: 8236, dtype: datetime64[ns]]
```

The reason for such idea is to ease my calculation between column later on. Any insight or other methods would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `Series.where`:

```
df['temperature'] = df['timestamp'].where(df['sensor'].eq('temperature'), 'not related')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.where() to give values on a condition. So for example you can use the command as below to say:
1- if df['sensor'] == 'temperature', then get the corresponding value from df['timestamp'].
2- If not, then set the value to 'not related'.
3- Finally, save the result to a new column in the dataframe and call it 'temperature'.
This is done in the following one-liner.

This should work:

```
df['temperature'] = np.where(df['sensor'] == 'temperature', df['timestamp'], 'not related')
```